# How can we type annotate arguments of decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator, typing

Suppose we're developing a decorator that prints contents of a first argument of decorated function, like the below.

```py
def printcontent(f):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        xs = args[0]
        for x in xs:
            print(x)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return func

@printcontent
def mysum(xs):
    return sum(xs)
```

Let's add type annotation on `printcontent`.
I would like to express that the `f` given to `printcontent` should accept `Iterable` as its first positional argument.

My unsuccessful attempt is following:

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, Iterable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def printcontent(f: Callable[Concatenate[Iterable[int], P], R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[Iterable[int], P], R]:
    def func(xs: Iterable[int], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        for x in xs:
            print(x)
        return f(xs, *args, **kwargs)
    return func

@printcontent
def mysum(xs: list[int]) -> int:
    return sum(xs)
```

This code does not type check. The problem is on application of `printcontent` to `mysum`. Mypy says:

```bash
error: Argument 1 to "printcontent" has incompatible type "Callable[[list[int]], int]"; expected "Callable[[Iterable[int]], int]"  [arg-type]
```

I think the cause of this is that argument types of functions is contravariant so subtype `list[int]` is not acceptable as an argument where `Iterable[int]` is expected.

My question is how can we annotate this decorator ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is myy successful attempt. Any advice or comments will be appreciated.

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, Iterable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
XS = TypeVar("XS", bound=Iterable)


def printcontent(f: Callable[Concatenate[XS, P], R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[XS, P], R]:
    def func(xs: XS, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        for x in xs:
            print(x)
        return f(xs, *args, **kwargs)
    return func


@printcontent # This type checks
def mysum(xs: list[int]) -> int:
    return sum(xs)

@printcontent # This does not type check
def plus1(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1
```